# Exclusion in SQL server WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to exclude only If ColumnA = 'SA' exclude ColumnB not like '%Prev%' and ColumnB not like '%old%'. If columnA = 'BA' I want to keep them. exp:

> ```
> select columnA
>     from Table
>     where columnA ='SA' and ColumnB not like '%Prev%' and ColumnB not like '%old%'
> ```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? They are not the same - please tag a single RDBMS. And please show sample data and expected results (as formatted text *not* images).

Comment: Please, post the question in the question input field, not in the title. Also correct DBMS tags.

Comment: @astentx fixed as suggested

Answer (score 1):

You want `or`:

```
select columnA
from Table
where (columnA = 'SA' and ColumnB not like '%Prev%' and ColumnB not like '%old%') or
      columnA <> 'SA'
```

If `columnA` can be `NULL`, the logic also needs to take that into account.

Answer (score 1):

The `or` logical operator should do the trick:

```sql
SELECT columnA
FROM   mytable
WHERE  columnA != 'SA' OR (ColumnB NOT LIKE '%Prev%' AND ColumnB NOT LIKE '%old%')
```

Note that the parenthesis aren't strictly required, but I think they make the query easier to read.

Comment: For such questions it's better to say they are required to form a habit put them explicitly in combination of OR/AND and remove the need to debug long chain of ORs and ANDs. When person got skilled enough he or she will learn that they were not required by himself or herself, but understand the charm of their presence ;)